# Convertir un int en varchar en WHERE sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi consulta radica en la necesidad de realizar una selección por medio de un like a la tabla, la cual posee un dato varchar y otro int. Ejemplo de la estructura de la tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE prueba(
    id INT IDENTITY,
    numero int,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_prueba PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Un ejemplo de selección que he realizado es:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECCIONARPRUEBA
    @par VARCHAR(150)  
AS 
SELECT p.id, p.numero, p.nombre from prueba p
    WHERE ( LOWER (p.nombre) LIKE LOWER (@par)  OR  LOWER(p.numero) LIKE LOWER(@par))
```

Esto es un pequeño ejemplo, ya que he intentado por los siguientes métodos, realizado un convert, cast, concat al numero en el where y ninguno a resultado ya que cuando quiero filtrar por el numero no me lo efectúa. Agradecería mucho su colaboración.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible hacerlo con `CAST`, lo que no es necesario en el caso del campo númerico es hacer un `LOWER` del campo, ya que no hay mayúsculas, puede que por ese lado fallara. Dejo un ejemplo que espero te sirva.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id INT,
    numero int,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO test (id, numero, nombre) VALUES (1,1,'nombre1');
INSERT INTO test (id, numero, nombre) VALUES (1,11,'nombre1');
INSERT INTO test (id, numero, nombre) VALUES (1,1,'nombre2');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE ( LOWER (nombre) LIKE LOWER('%1%')  
       OR CAST(numero as VARCHAR) LIKE LOWER('%1%'));

| id  | numero | nombre  |
| --- | ------ | ------- |
| 1   | 1      | nombre1 |
| 1   | 11     | nombre1 |
| 1   | 1      | nombre2 |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE ( LOWER (nombre) LIKE LOWER('%11%')  
       OR CAST(numero as VARCHAR) LIKE LOWER('%11%'));

| id  | numero | nombre  |
| --- | ------ | ------- |
| 1   | 11     | nombre1 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Yo lo evaluaba el lower en el sentido de que bien no cambiar el tamaño de la letra consideraría que no afectaría. Nos tante. Es una muy buena recomendación para posibles problemas a futuro y mejor prevenir. Aunque en este caso fue más culpa mía que otra cosa, ya que con su comentario y un poco mas descansado, vi que el error no era ese específicamente, sino era en otra comparación que realizaba. De igual manera agradezco su compendario y su recomendación. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema @Luis Chavarria? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda